# Setting Selected Index of NSPopUpButtonCell in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsmenuitem, nspopupbuttoncell

I populate a column in an `NSTableView` with `NSPopUpButtonCell` instances (just dragged such a cell to a column in IB).
Everything works fine, except for one thing : when I try to set the selected item index of one of the `NSPopUpButtonCell` instances by returning the appropriate index in `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` the menu still highlights the first item.
I checked the value that I return in that method, and it is correct (so it's not always zero).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I added a call to  `-selectItemAtIndex:` the 'willDisplayCell' delegate method.